# Pop up a browse Site Content dialog through code

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, modal-dialog, spdialog

I recently watched a video which popped-up a SharePoint Dialog box (Webpage Dialog) to browse site content, and then return the selection value to a text box. Is it possible to invoke this dialog box through code **to Browse Site Content** and return the selected value to a variable/Control ? Or do we have to implement this from scratch ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following JavaScript function when called will pop up the browse dialog in a modal window and if the user makes a selection will return an array of four elements:

- element 0: guids of list, web
- element 1: base URL (e.g.`/sites/sitecollection2`)
- element 2: library display name (e.g. `Documents`)
- element 3: library URL (e.g. `/sites/sitecollection2/Shared Documents`)

You can examine the querystring on the `PickerTreeView` page to see what the parameters are and how they are used.

```
function showBrowseDialog() {
    var qs = 'title=RouterPickerSelectListTitle&text=RouterPickerSelectListText&filter=websListsFolders&root=&selection=&featureId=&errorString=&iconUrl=/_layouts/15/images/smt_icon.gif?rev=39&scopeToWeb=true&requireCT=&sourceId=';
    var url = SP.ClientContext.get_current().get_url() + '/_layouts/15/PickerTreeView.aspx?' + qs;

    var result = window.showModalDialog(url, null, "dialogHeight: 700px; dialogWidth: 525px; dialogTop: px; dialogLeft: px; edge: Raised; center: Yes; resizable: No; status: Yes;");
    if(result)
        alert('You selected ' + result[3]);
    else
        alert('You hit cancel');
}
```

Comment: Note this will not work in chrome and possibly firefox due to the lack of support for showModalDialog.  For those browsers you need to just use a standard window.